# SQL to end users: pros and cons

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, reporting

Once upon a time, far far away in a distant galaxy I was a witness to a discussion between a couple of developers. The subject was if it's a good idea to give end users access to a production SQL server (MS SQL 2008) in order to give them ability to make their own reports against their own data.

It was a request from business people -- "Our clients want to make custom reports".

A guy who proposed this, claimed that:

1. He was able to give users "read-only access" through set of
   permissions and make the system absolutely safe.
2. SQL initially
   was an "end-user" language and may be so now.
3. Having permissions
   to run SQL queries, users would be able to do what they want not
   disturbing developers and support.

Other guys who were against this claimed:

1. It's pretty easy to crash MS SQL having even max. restricted access.
2. Exposing SQL and database structure to end users is not a good idea anyway; it's a bad design.
3. SQL is too complicated to non-programmers, and, therefore, it won't make their life easier.

What do you think about giving end users access to SQL?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would "exposing SQL and database structures to end users" be "bad design"? If the DB design is good, there is no reason to hide it.

Comment: In my humble opinion DB is an internal system feature. End users usually have no idea how the system works, and they shouldn't know it; it's a black box. If we expose DB to end users we expose a valuable part of its internal design whick is not good. IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make some things safer by not just limiting users to read-only access, but also by turning on the [query governor cost limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191219%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).  That will attempt to do some cost analysis of the queries prior to running them, and if they exceed the predefined threshold it will refuse to run them.

Even better than this would be to have a cloned database available for querying.  This could be something as simple as a separate server running off of a backup of the production system.  Depending on how "live" your data needed to be, you could adjust the backup/restore interval accordingly.

As far as whether it's a good idea to expose the database to direct querying for non-programmers, that still depends on just how savvy the users are.  Could they be taught SQL?  It's really not that hard for simple things.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely upon your user(s).  If the user is technically capable or interested in developing this skill set, they can alleviate a big chunk of the workload from the programmers.

One the other hand, I know boneheads that will never understand normalized data structures, and their runaway queries have repeatedly crashed the server.

If you decide to go for it, create a separate database mirror for reporting if possible.  Update it nightly so they have fairly current data.  Of course, this isn't ideal if they have real-time reporting needs.

Answer (score 1):

The arguements against, are very weak. If the users, can't write sql, why do you care? There are report writing tools (Crystal Reports), that can take care of a lot of this.

Some companies that use other software have staff members who do know how to query a database or they can hire a consultant.

You'll never get into the corporate market with a lock on database access.

EDIT: A set of views can be built into the database for a majority of the user needs. This way they don't have to worry about complex joins.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of giving end users access to write their own queries against a production database, even with read-only access, is that your performance will drop through the floor and into the sub-basement.  If an end-user can write SQL, they usually can't write it very well.  At some point the'll discover cursors (if in MS SQL) and/or they'll over-think their joins.  They'll pull in every table they can find.  If you want to make them happy, do a nightly dump into a non-production database on a separate machine (or well-limited VM) and tell them to knock themselves out.  Pro tip: also tell them that you won't have any time to support it.

I'm not anti-end user, I just don't think they're to be trusted to write queries in anything resembling an efficient manner.  If you have a select few who you think can be trusted, try it out with them and lock them out if they ever share their password.

Answer (score 1):

It depends who is responsible for product after deployment.
If situation is clear(you sell code with everything without support) then why not?
It's not your problem then.

In the situation when you have to take care of everything and are responsible for uptime I wouldn't advise to do it even for read only.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a database account safe against unwanted changes, but you can't make it safe against performance issues. The end user could easily create a query that would lock up all the tables and run for a long time. It won't actually crash the database, but the users will experience it as a crash.

If you are ok with the report function potentially hanging the system, you can go ahead.

However, I must say that I doubt the usefulness of this. As always with statistics you have to know that what you ask for is exactly what you wanted to ask for, otherwise the result is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately there is business value in enabling end-user analysis of data. Direct access via SQL is one way to do that.

One disadvantage hasn't been mentioned yet. By default in SQL Server readers will block writers. That means you probably need to enable snapshot isolation (or maybe use database snapshots or read-only copies of the DB) otherwise even the simplest, most innocent user queries could cripple your production system.

Perhaps surprisingly, even though Microsoft introduced snapshot isolation mode 7 years ago it still seems to be common to see systems go into production with it turned off (the default is READ COMMITTED without SI). So before allowing users to access your production systems you may need to make that change and do some retesting and refactoring.